# Dismiss modal from a view in a tab bar view

Tags: swift, view, modal-dialog, uitabbarcontroller

**How can I dismiss a modal view opened from a view in a tab bar view and stays on that view?**

I have a tab bar view after login in and there are two views on the tab view (Clients and Profile).

On clients I have a list of clients and I can open another view that shows invoices.

Tapping on an invoice, it shows me the details of a particular invoice.

On this view, there is an actionView with some buttons.

One of those button is "Make Payment".

When tapped on Make Payment, a modal windows is shown.

However, when I tap on a cancel button, it removes all the views and goes back to the login view (initial view)

Invoice View

```
@IBAction func showActionAlert(_ sender: Any) {
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

let payButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Make Payment", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakePaymentViewController")
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

})

let voidButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Void", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
})

let deleteButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
})

let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in })
alertController.addAction(payButton)
alertController.addAction(voidButton)
alertController.addAction(deleteButton)
alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
self.navigationController!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Modal View

```
 @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
     let tmpController :UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController;
     self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {()->Void in
         tmpController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
     });
 }
```

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

The controller you're presenting it from is your **navigationController** in which your navigation stack is.

If you present several **viewControllers** from your **navigationController** and then dismiss all the presented Controllers from the parent/presentingViewController(which is navigationController) all viewControllers that are presented on are dismissed.

Instead of presenting it like this :

```
self.navigationController!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

do this

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And while dismissing do:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: i changed it on showActionAlert but it still goes to the login view

Comment: I added a pic of the storyboard. Modal is the dark view. Login view is the initial view

Answer (score 0):

I changed the cancelButton action and it worked:

```
@IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```